# Transform SymPy Solver into a function of inputs, being able to add the formulas, symbols through the Python terminal instead of directly in the Codes

Tags: python, math, input, sympy

I want to transform SymPy Solver into a function of inputs, being able to add the formulas, symbols through the Python terminal instead of directly in the Codes, and do this whit this code:

```
import sympy as sm

X, Y, Z = sm.symbols("X, Y, Z")
depth = sm.Eq(X, Y*Z)
S = sm.solve(depth, Z)

print(S)

# This formula is the equivalent of: X=Y*Z
# As I asked to isolate Y (on line 4), if I give RUN, it will return as ([X/Z]), because Y=X/Z
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! So you want to write a competitor to Mathematica in Python? That's a worthy goal, but it's a more ambitious project than you may suspect. I'm sure there are at least one or two people here who would know exactly how they would tackle such a project. But I think a useful answer would not fit into the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

Comment: `sympy.sympify` takes a string.  Explore that, but don't expect a complete solution.